# Remove an attribute if another is the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I have this in HTML:

```
<a class="clickImage" href="http://domain.com/a_0_full.jpg" data-lightbox="group">initialize</a>
<a class="imageZoom" href="http://domain.com/a_0_full.jpg"></a>
<a class="imageZoom" href="http://domain.com/a_1_full.jpg"></a>
```

I want to give different `data-lightbox` (noGroup) for `a.imageZoom` with same `href` as `a.clickImage` and same `data-lightbox` (group) with different `href`.

this is what I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clickImage").click(function() {
        var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".imageZoom").attr('data-lightbox','group');
        if($('.imageZoom').attr('href') == addressValue) {
            $(this).attr('data-lightbox','noGroup');
        }
    });
});
```

from what I understand, it gives `noGroup` to all links with `a.imageZoom`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.filter()` for filtering out element that have same href as that in variable `addressValue`. and then set the attribute `data-lightbox` as `no-Group` to them:

```
$('.imageZoom').filter(function(){
   return $(this).attr('href') == addressValue;
}).attr('data-lightbox','noGroup');
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be this way:

```js
    $(".clickImage").click(function() {
      var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
      $(".imageZoom").attr('data-lightbox', function(i) {
        return (addressValue == $(this).attr('href')) ? "noGroup" : "group";
      });
      return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="clickImage" href="http://domain.com/a_0_full.jpg" data-lightbox="group">initialize</a>
<a class="imageZoom" href="http://domain.com/a_0_full.jpg">one</a><!--applies noGroup to this.-->
<a class="imageZoom" href="http://domain.com/a_1_full.jpg">two</a>
```